# In slow_log table sql_text column is BLOB

Tags: mysql, mysql-5.6, mysql-5.7

We enabled slow_log to debug slow queries. But In slow_log table  sql_text column is BLOB.. It used to work fine before on 5.6 but now shows blob on 5.7

(Clarification)  When saving the slowlog to a `TABLE`, what happens to `BLOBs` and `TEXT` strings that cannot be safely stored in some standard column?  Apparently, `TEXT` values are stored into a `BLOB`.  In that case, how do I get back the `TEXT` in the desired `CHARACTER SET`?

Comment: Writing the slow log to FILE?  Or TABLE?

Comment: slow_log table..

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In 5.7 ; column sql_text is changed to BLOB... Hence, you need to use 
select CONVERT(sql_text USING utf8  ) from mysql.slow_log ;